# Why can't I access my website hosted in Elastic Beanstalk using the url generated by it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, nginx, ip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I recently hosted my website using Elastic Beanstalk.When I try to access the website using private IP , I can access the website and it works perfectly fine.
The following is the screenshot of my website , when I access it using the private IP of the EC-2 Instance.
[The screenshot of the working website using private IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qktQF.png)

My problem is that when I try to access my website using the url generated by the Elastic Beanstalk , I cannot access it and it gives me the following error.
[The screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhlYa.png)

I am fairly new to AWS. So can someone tell , what is it that I am doing wrong? How can I rectify it?

Comment: Please provide the url.

Comment: sorry can't do that.....it's protected by firewalls.

Comment: oh, okay. did you try clearing the cache or using different browser? I have never used Elastic Beanstalk myself.

Comment: It is working in no browsers...I tried opera,chrome and IE...and I cleared the cache as well.

Comment: you are using apache, nginx or IIS as your server?

Comment: I am using nginx

Comment: Could you add more information on how your VPC/network is setup?  How are you able to access the private IPs?  Are you accessing this from another machine in that VPC or do you have some sort of VPN setup to allow access to the private address space of your VPC?  It appears this configuration along with your security groups and NACLs are most likely the cause of the connectivity issues.

Answer (score 0):

This must be linked to the security rules of your ec2 instance. To modify that, check the "Instances" field of your EB configuration and look at which security rules are checked. You can update these rules on the ec2 dashboard.

Comment: To add to this, check the source information on your security groups. It appears it is allowing requests in from local traffic but not allowing requests in from the internet. This could also be caused by the NACLs on your subnets (you can see these in the VPC console) but this probably less likely.